# Entity Framework Fetch count of child entities as a property

Tags: c#, sql, entity-framework, entity-framework-6

I have 2 entities which depict `Post`, and `Comments`.

```
public class Post
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public ICollection<Comment> Comments { get; set; }

    //other properties 


    //Unmapped property
    public int NumberOfComments { get; set; }

}

public class Comment
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public Post Post { get; set; }
    public int PostId { get; set; }

    // other properties
}
```

Now I want the `NumberOfComments` property to be populated with the actual count of comments of the post.

- Tried projecting the results of the query in to a collection of posts
  model didn't workout.
- Tried joining the table and then grouped by post id still didn't
  seems to work.

I cannot simply `return p.Comments.Count;` as the property definition as I'm not including the comments during the query.  I only wants the count of the comments, not the whole collection in memory.

Comment: `public int NumberOfComments { get { return Comments.Count(); } }` ?

Comment: I'm not including the comments. i just want to get the number of comments only.

Comment: I think you'll have to explicitly request it in your query `select new Post { Id = p.Id, NumberOfComments = p.Comments.Count()}`?

Comment: juharr thanks. but it would throw up with "entity cannot be constructed in a linq to entities query"

Comment: @Aneef Just do something like `... select new { Id= p.Id, NumberOfComments = p.Comments.Count() }).AsEnumerable().Select(p => new Post { Id = p.Id, NumberOfComments = p.NumberOfComments})` then.  Or consider creating a separate DTO for the specific data you want to use and keep your other layers separate from your entities.

Comment: @juharr but such entity will be detached from context (so, cannot be updated or removed for example).

Comment: @Evk That's not always a bad thing.

Comment: @Evk what juharr said is the approach i was taking already. only thing i dont like is that code looks bit ugly. but it servers the purpose. will check it when i start my day tomorrow and get back with the updates. my only worry is whether this would run the count for each row separately or would do a join and group by in the generated SQL

Comment: In this case its bad, because it is not immediatly clear. Then author changes some property, calls save changes and nothing happens, and a long debugging session begins... But if there is absolutely no need to update or remove that Post - why not (still better to use DTO and not pollute entity with property which does not always contain correct value).

Answer (score 3):

This is the way I have found to do it.

The following classes would be necessary:

```
public class PostExtraData
{
    public Post post { get; set; }
    public int NumberOfComments { get; set; } 
}

public class Post
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public ICollection<Comment> Comments { get; set; }

    //other properties 

}

public class Comment
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public Post Post { get; set; }
    public int PostId { get; set; }

    // other properties
}
```

Do not add the `PostExtraData` class to the context.

And in the controller we wrote the following (in this case, to obtain the list of posts):

```
return _context.Post
       .Select(p => new PostExtraData
       {
           Post= p,
           NumberOfComments = p.Comments.Count(),
       })
       .ToList();
```

Answer (score -1):

Suposing you always retrieve the Comments navigation you could do something like the following:

```
public class Post
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public ICollection<Comment> Comments { get; set; }

    //other properties 

    //Unmapped property: Since it's value depends on the Comments collection
    //we don't need to define the setter. If the collection is null, it'll
    //return zero.
    public int NumberOfComments
    {
        get
        {
            return this.Comments?.Count() ?? 0;
        }
    }
}
```

About this line... `return this.Comments?.Count() ?? 0;`

Here we're using two null operators, the Null Conditional Operator `?` and the Null Coalescing Operator `??`.

The first one avoids the code to raise an error if the Comments property is null by immediately returning the value null before calling `.Count()`, the second operates when the left expression is null returns the right expression, so if `this.Comments?.Count()` returns null it'll give you 0.

Comment: see my answers below. it would be always 0.bcoz i'm not always retrieving comments

Comment: please see my response and juharrs response in Matts answer. I'm aware about the ?? operator and navigation properties. but just confused with the above

Comment: Ok, if you're not retrieving the comments with each post, maybe you could do a count separately in another query (you'll have to return the setter to the NumberOfComments property).

myPost.NumberOfComments =.db.Comments.Where(c => c.PostId == postId).Count();

Comment: AaronBC. that wouldn't be an efficient way i think.

Comment: As for the generated query i think it would use the COUNT() sql function in the database so it won't retrieve the data to objects and count in memory later. @Aneef